# delegatingHandler (webapi) equivalent in servicestack

Tags: asp.net-web-api, servicestack

I am trying to migrate to servicestack framework from asp.net mvc4 webapi framework. I have a delegatingHandler in webapi what is equivalent to this in servicestack?

This is where I will validate my request and return a custom response without going any further.

MY DELEGATINGHANDLER

```
public class xyzDH : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        int maxLengthAllowed = 200;
        long? contentLen = request.Content.Headers.ContentLength; 
        if (contentLen > maxLengthAllowed)
        {
            var defaultResponse = ResponseHelper.GetBaseResponse("Content Lenght Issue", true, UploadLogSizeIssue);
            return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent(defaultResponse.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "message/http")
                    };
                return response;
            });
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a good idea to glance over [ServiceStack's simple Architecture](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Architecture-overview) to give you an overall idea of how ServiceStack is put together.

#### [Custom Hooks, Filters and Extensibility points](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations)

ServiceStack allows a number of custom hooks and extensibility points identified in the [Order of Operations wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations). You can use a Custom [Filter Attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) or [Global Filters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) to do this which lets you write directly to the response after which point you can call the `httpResponse.EndServiceStackRequest()` extension method to signal that no more processing should happen to the request.

#### [Validators](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation)

Since you're asking in the context of Request validation you should have a look at [ServiceStack's built-in validation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation) which allows declarative validation using the built-in FluentValidation.

#### [Error Handling](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling)

In a lot of cases just throwing a normal C# exception is all you need. ServiceStack provides a great story around this which includes serializing the exceptions in Service Clients. Read the [Error Handling wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling) to learn about different ways of customizing exception handling.

### Using a Global Request Filter

This is how you can re-write your WebApi Delegating Handler with a ServiceStack [Global Request Filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters):

```
this.RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) =>
{
    int maxLengthAllowed = 200;
    if (httpReq.ContentLength > maxLengthAllowed)
    {
        //httpRes.StatusCode = 200; //No-op, not needed since its the default
        //Guess it could also be "message/http" but never heard of it
        httpRes.ContentType = "text/plain"; 
        httpRes.Write("Content Length Issue"); //Whatever you want in body
        httpRes.EndServiceStackRequest(); //No more processing for this request
    }
});
```

**Warning:** It is not recommended to return `200 OK` for an invalid HTTP request as shown above. If the request is not valid it should be a `400 BadRequest` error which is what ServiceStack will automatically write whenever you [throw a C# Exception inheriting ArgumentException](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling).

Comment: So for example if I would like to do validation based on content Length, If content length > 200 then return a custom httpresponse (httpstatuscode.ok). where can I do this?

Comment: Why would you want to return a 200 OK without processing the request first? If it's OK, leave the request un-touched and just let it through to get handled by the service, otherwise write a HTTP Error to the response and close the request with `httpRes.EndServiceStackRequest()`. Also you can do this validation inisde the Service with `if (base.Request.ContentLength < 200) throw ex`

Comment: Because its a business logic (to not accept content length above 200) and not an actual error, I am trying to return 200 with an appropriate message

Comment: It should never be a `200 OK` (which signals to the client that the request is fine) it should instead be a `400 Bad Request` which ServiceStack writes by default whenever you throw any exception inheriting from `ArgumentException`. I'll update my answer to show how you can do what you want with a Global Filter. If you don't want it to apply globally use a [Request Filter Attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) and apply to and as needed.

Comment: for your convenience I have added the code I currently have in webapi, can you please show me how I can get to that using global filter or whatever is appropriate

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please Note adding a more descriptive question that we can answer is for your convenience - it also saves us time since we don't have to guess what you mean, please do this for future Q's.